# $.get Update XML Data in Real Time

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, html, bootstrap-4

I'm building a page that has a bootstrap carousel that displays some temperature information. The data is loaded from an XML file and this file will be fed with new data whenever a change occurs.

I'm doing the tests by editing the file manually and I can't see the changes that I make. I already tried setTimeout and setInterval (setInterval repeated the block several times, it wouldn't do any good if it worked).

Could you help me with a possible solution?

```js
function temperatures() {
    'use strict';
    $.get('temperature.xml', function (data) {
        $(data).find('temperature').each(function () {
            let $temperature = $(this);
            let type = $temperature.find('type').text();
            let value = $temperature.find('value').text();

            let temperatures = '<div class="carousel-item temperature">';
            temperatures += '<span class="sensor-value">' + value + '</span>';
            temperatures += '<span class="sensor-title">' + type + '</span>';
            temperatures += '</div>';

            $('.temperatures').append($(temperatures));
        });
    });
    setTimeout(temperatures, 1000);
}

$(function () {
    temperatures();
});
```

Comment: Try appending a timestamp to the URL to prevent caching, or you can disable caching on all AJAX requests by using `$.ajaxSetup()`. ***However*** you should note that AJAX polling is a very bad idea for production systems. If this is for anything more than a personal test, you should look in to using WebSockets or Server Sent Events instead, although note that will involve some base level server logic changes.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan! I will research more about Server Sent Events instead!